# Spring Security Oauth + JWT for native apps

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth, jwt, authorization

In spring boot app I need to implement combined authentication - custom jwt and OAuth providers (google, facebook, etc). My boot app works as an API for mobile apps only.
So my plan is to generate custom jwt for all requests, but I don't have a mind how to handle OAuth authentication and convert it to my custon JWT. Perhaps I have poor knowlenges how it works on mobile client.

So do someone have implementation sample with elegant and simple solution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that some of the "social" identity providers you want to use will either not allow you to use their authorization-server directly or just wont deliver JWTs (some only support token introspection).

I strongly advise you pick an OIDC **authorization-server** capable of identity federation to proxy all heterogeneous identity providers. There are plenty of solutions out there, either on premise (like Keycloak) or in the cloud (Auth0, Okta and Cognito are samples, but almost each cloud provider comes with its solution too). This will also provide you with a centralized place to handle additional user security data you might need (like roles).

This authorization-server will be the only identity issuer for your Spring REST API which you'll configure as **resource-server**. See [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for details.

For mobile **clients**, the way I do it is redirect users from the app to authorization-server for login (this opens in system browsers), and then setup "deep links" for response with authorization-code to open in the native-app. The framework to end the OAuth2 authorization-code flow (exchange the code for tokens) depends on the framework you use to write your native apps.

Comment: Make sense, thank you. I come up with this approach, but decide to ask is someone have easier way to deal with it. But seems for my case I can't avoid auth-server